# How display data fetched from database on a jsp page in dropdown list using struts2 with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts2

How display data fetched from database on a JSP in drop down list using struts?  I have done the code for the drop-down list using array list for the city but error has occurred.

```
HTTP Status 500 - type Exception report message description 
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.   
exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 
  'location': The requested list key '%{city}' could not be resolved 
   as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type.
```

I have done this code for the city list are as follows:

JAVA code

```
 public class Event extends ActionSupport{

 private String description;
 public List<String> city;
 public List<String> getCity() {
 return city;
 }
 public void setCity(List<String> city) {
 this.city = city;
 }   
 public String execute() throws Exception{

 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:20976";  
 String dbName = "chetan";  
 String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 String user = "root";
 String pass = "root121";
 Connection con = null;  
 Statement stmt = null;  
 ResultSet rs = null;  
 try {  
    Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();  
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, user,pass);  
    stmt = con.createStatement();  
 } catch (Exception e) {  
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
 }  

 rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from City");  
 while (rs.next()) {  
    city.add(rs.getString("Location"));  


 }  

 return SUCCESS;  

 }
```

JSP CODE for the City

```
 <s:select name="location" label="Location" headerValue="Select City" list="city" />
 <s:submit value="Submit" method="execute" key="submit" align="center" />
```

Comment: What did you try, where you stuck ?

Comment: I have done the code for the drop-down list using array list for the city but error was occurred.

Comment: Please post the code with error message

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'location': The requested list key '%{city}' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type.

Comment: and code ? <!---------->

Comment: I have edit my question you can see the code which I have done for the City list.

Comment: Have you got the data in the Arraylist or collection you are using. Get the jsp code with `struts2` tag here.

Comment: It is jasper exception you also need to add your JSP code

Comment: Also added JSP code for city (i.e. in updated question)

Comment: no one is here to solve this my error.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise arrayList before you append items in the list

```
city = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In your action you have declared the list name as `city`, so in your select the `list` attribute should also be the same

```
<s:select label="City List" headerKey="-1" list="city" name="whatever" />
```

Also the `name` attribute must be without parenthesis, according to my knowledge and should match the variable name you are declaring in the submit action.

Comment: because of headerKey not issue for this if it is present or not. 
for  location  i have done the same code in jsp also in other jsp I have done 2 jsp code for the list

Comment: The exception is with a select with name `location`. Can you show that code also?

Comment: for the location:

<s:select name="location" label="Location" headerValue="Select City" list="city" />

Comment: Initialise the arrayList before adding items.Put this before you add any item to the list `city = new ArrayList<String>()`. Take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/)